# In ASP.NET MVC, can I specifically check a user's local role membership?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, windows-authentication

In my ASP.NET MVC 3, application, I want to authorize users against a local role (e.g., Builtin\Administrators). I specifically don't want to query the AD server for the user's role memberships, as this can be very slow. Is there some way to query only for a user's local role membership(s)? I'm on .NET 4.5, Windows Server 2008 R2.